# Configuring an Intel compiler from MSVC 2019 built-in CMake

Tags: cmake, visual-studio-2019, icc

Recent Visual Studio versions support CMake natively, with documentation for compilation with [MSVC, Clang, and for linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/cmake-projects-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019).  However, there is no official documentation for configuring the Intel compiler.

What is the best way to configure the Intel compiler using Visual Studio's native CMake?  Can I create a [custom environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/cmakesettings-reference?view=vs-2019#environments)?

I found [one forum post](https://software.intel.com/pt-br/node/806872) that attempts to solve the problem, but it relies on the Windows CLI to launch Visual Studio.  I've also submitted a [feature request](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/1145160/support-intel-cc-compiler-from-cmake.html) for native CMake support for the Intel C/C++ compiler within Visual Studio.